# htaccess - Rewriterule redirects to wrong URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

Anything that is not an existing file should be forwarded to `index.php`. However, there's a directory, `images`, there are sevenal images in it, but no `index.php|html`. When I open `localhost/images`, without a closeing slash (`localhost/images/` works fine), it redirects me to `localhost/images/?p=images`. How should I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because of the `mod_dir` module that runs after `mod_rewrite` adding a trailing slash to directories. You should add a condition to avoid rewriting directories in your rule. Also add a trailing slash using a redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```